# how to access the css on focus in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

well guys, i have this function that checks for the value of two text-boxes and depending on whether they are equal or not, does specific things, here is the function:

```
function ajx()
{
    var e_value = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var text_value = document.getElementById('text2').value;
    try{
    if (e_value == text_value)
    {
        document.getElementById('email').style.border = '2px solid red';
        document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = 'email has been taken';
    }
else if (e_value == "" || e_value == " "|| e_value.includes('@') == false||  e_value.includes('.') == false)
    {
        document.getElementById('email').style.border = '2px solid none';
        document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = '';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('email').style.border = '2px solid blue';
        document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = '';
    }
}

catch(e)
{
    document.write(e);
}
}
```

the main problem i am having here is that this code:

```
document.getElementById('email').style.border = '2px solid none';
```

only works when i click outside the text-box, is it possible to make it work whiles the cursor is inside the text-box(on-focus), and how can i archive it?
thanks !!!

this is the html:

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
    <input class="input100 climate" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" onkeydown="ajx()" onmousemove="ajx();" onmouseover="ajx();" oninput="ajx();">

<label id="mes" style="color: red;" ></label>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> only works when i click outside the text-box, is it possible to make it work whiles the cursor is inside the text-box(on-focus)

Seems like you are calling the function `onblur` (focus out). To me you can use `oninput` event which will fire on every input instead of `focus`:

**Demo:**

```js
function ajx(){
  var e_value = document.getElementById('email').value.trim();
  var text_value = document.getElementById('text2').value.trim();
  try{
    if (e_value == text_value){
      document.getElementById('email').style.border = '2px solid red';
      document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = 'email has been taken';
    }
    else if (e_value == "" || !e_value.includes('@') || !e_value.includes('.'))
    {
      document.getElementById('email').style.border = '2px solid none';
      document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = '';
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('email').style.border = '2px solid blue';
      document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = '';
    }
  }
  catch(e){
    document.write(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
  <input class="input100 climate" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" oninput="ajx();">
  <input id="text2"/> <br>
  <label id="mes" style="color: red;" ></label>
</div>
```

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil, please update the question with relevant HTML:)

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil, there is no element with `id="text2"` and `id="mes"`!!!

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil, also you do not need any of `onkeydown="ajx()" onmousemove="ajx();" onmouseover="ajx();"`

Comment: there are elements with text2 and mes, text 2 is generated by php and mess is the label name, and may i ask how do u guys put code in your comments?

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil, comments are not the right place to post code, though I have updated the answer with demo solution:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204792/discussion-between-curtis-crentsil-and-mamun).

Answer (score 0):

Use the "onfocus" event to achieve it:

```
document.getElementById("email").onfocus = function() {
  myFunction();
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("email").style.border = '2px solid red';
}
```

Comment: so for that  //some code...  how would i change the border color?

Comment: i added document.getElementById("email").onfocus = function() {
     style.border = '2px solid red';
}; but now i can't type in the text box again

Comment: Take a look to the edited answer. It works just fine!